# Spring Boot Run Jar file in linux

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have developed a Spring Boot Application using Restfull API. The application working perfectly in STS. But now i am trying to run a jar file in linux, any idea.

Comment: Where does PHP come into this?

Comment: There is a spring boot plugin that repackages they app in a single jar. Do you use that?

Comment: which errors are you getting?? what command line are you executing?

Comment: Dear, IF you r problem  resoled from answer , you can take it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can generate runnable jar file using 2 ways.

**a. Exporting as JAR file from STS.**

> Right click on project in STS --> click on Export --> search for jar
>   --> click on JAR file --> select project --> select resource to export --> Select checkbox : Export Java source files and resources --> select the export destination --> give a name for JAR file (for
>   example abcd.jar) click finish to generate JAR file.

**b. Using Maven.**

> First, make sure that you have the [repackage goal included in your
>   build setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html), then use the Maven package target. The simplest way
>   to do this is to run mvn package from the command line (you may need
>   to install the Maven CLI package for your OS); you can also
>   right-click the POM in Eclipse and "Run As" to execute specific Maven
>   operations from within Eclipse.

To run JAR file open command/terminal prompt and reach to destination where JAR file was created. then execute command **java -jar abcd.jar**

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the steps

1. check the version which you have installed in Linux

```
java -version
```

2. Install the JDK corresponding to your application version which you have created application

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-version-what you want JDK verson  -jre
// example - sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

3. Run the application simply typing

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```